# AngularJS date input not showing initial value inside directives in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, date, firefox, angularjs-directive

I have a date input that is bound to a model. If the input is inside a directive, then the date input doesn't have it's initial value set. Updating the input does update the model, it's just the initial value that isn't set. It works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

[Here is the relevant codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzydRa)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
 <input type=text ng-model="mainDateModel">
 <input type=date ng-model="mainDateModel">
 Main date model: {{mainDateModel}}
 <dir></dir>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
angular.module('app').controller('main', function($scope) {
 $scope.mainDateModel = new Date();
})
angular.module('app').directive('dir', function() {
 return {
  template: '<input type=text ng-model="dirDateModel">' +
    '<input type=date ng-model="dirDateModel">' + 
    ' Dir date model: {{dirDateModel}}',
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.dirDateModel = new Date();
  }
 }
})
```

It should show 12/13/2018 where it says mm/dd/yyyy
[image: Codepen screenshot]

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there an easy way to work around it? The text input is correctly initialized, just the date isn't.

Update:
[Here is the bug I filed in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1514040)

Comment: That codepen works for me in firefox. It's quite strange that for you isn't working. No errors in the console or something?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 65.0b4 (64-bit). I've added a screenshot to show where it isn't working.

Comment: My firefox version is 64.0, don't know if that's the problem. Maybe you could try downgrading your firefox version just for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with your browser version.
For me it works both in chrome and firefox.